# How to coordinate a list of Completable executions with RxJava?

Tags: rx-java, kotlin, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have a list of `BlockingTasks` that I want to run sequentially:

```
class BlockingTaskManager {
    val tasks = mutableListOf<BlockingTask>()

    fun run () : Completable {
        /* What can I put here in order to run
           all tasks and return a completable according with the
           requirements described below? */
    }
}

interface BlockingTask {

    fun run () : Completable

    fun getDescription(): String

    fun blockPipe(): Boolean
}
```

### Requirements

- If any `Completable` in the pipe finishes with error, the whole execution should stop.;
- When a `Completable` returned by `run()` finishes, either with error or success, a log containing the timestamp and the String returned by `getDescription()` should be issued;

---

I thought about using `Completable.concat { tasks }`, but I don't see how I can call `currentIterationTask.run()` and how to fail the pipe if `run()` results on error, as well as logging `currentInterationTask.getDescription()`.

Another idea was using `andThen()`, but I'm not sure if it will work as needed:

```
    tasks.forEachIndexed {
        idx, task ->
        var isBroken = false
        task.run()
                .doOnComplete {
                    logTaskCompletedSuccessfully(task)
                }
                .doOnError {
                    error ->
                    logTaskFailed(task, error)
                    isBroken = task.blockPipe()
                }
                .andThen {
                    if (!isBroken && idx < tasks.size) {
                        tasks[idx+1]
                    }
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in various ways:

```
 fun run(): Completable {
    return Completable.concat(tasks.map { task ->
        task.run()
                .doOnComplete { logTaskCompletedSuccessfully(task) }
                .doOnError { error ->
                    logTaskFailed(task, error)
                }
    })
}
```

sequential execution is achieved by the `concat` operator, error from some of the `Completable`s will stop the stream with `onError()`, and you will get the logging capability with either success or error.

as for the `blockPipe()` flag, if I understands correctly it is used to flag that the task has failed and you should break the stream, if that's the case, seems unnecessary to me, for any failure in the task, throw `Exception` instead of raising a flag, and the exception will break the stream with `onError`.

---

Another option is to use more reactive approach instead of iterating the tasks on the list, iterate it with `Observable`.
start with `Observable`, that iterates the list of tasks, and then `flatMap` each task to `Completable`. 
sequential execution is achieved here as you're not applying any Scheduler to each `Completable`, and hence the order of execution is maintained.

```
 fun run(): Completable {
    return Observable.fromIterable(tasks)
            .flatMapCompletable { task ->
                task.run()
                        .doOnComplete { logTaskCompletedSuccessfully(task) }
                        .doOnError { error ->
                            logTaskFailed(task, error)
                        }
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread() // Schedulers.io())
}
```